# Jquery UI draggable - left offset when adding new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I try to add div elements with variable texts to a container and make them draggable. Hier some source:

```
var $element = $('<div class="drag" style="display: inline-block; border : 1px dotted #fff; color : #fff; font-size : 26px; left : 0px;">').text('Test xyz');
$("#designer").append($element);
$element.draggable({ cursor: "move", containment : "#designer", grid: [ 20, 20 ]});
```

If I run this 5 times and drag the elements vertical in one line the left offset looks like:

```
> Test xyz
> _Test xyz
> __Test xyz
> ___Test xyz
> Test xyz
```

Why is there an offset and how can I manage this if I got other strings with different lengths?

Comment: I don't get the same result as you have described.  I think it may be due to the styles applied to the div the text is appended to - 'designer'.

Comment: I've set up a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/74rvrxhm

Comment: I updated the fiddle. Removed grid: [ 20, 20 ] .

Comment: Hi that is correct, but I need the grid!